# How to call from app in Ionic using href?

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have read many post but it seems I am doing something wrong.

```
<a href="tel:1234543" class="item item-icon-left" id="number">
    <i class="icon ion-earth"></i> Call
</a>
```

config file

```
 <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

When I run this on my device the button does nothing? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the code like this :

```
<a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555" id="number" class="item item-icon-left">
   <i class="icon ion-earth"></i> Call
</a>
```

**Config.xml**

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Sad to say it still does nothing. I am running it using Ionic view, apk install on android device. It just click and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

So here is reference for the future. For this to work, you need to build the apk and install. This will not work if you try to upload to ionic view, run in ionic lab,can not run the code from ionic lab to the actual device or emulator.